# jQuery: return string response in jquery ajax json call

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

I am passing json data to my generic handler page `GenericHandler.ashx.cs` using jquery ajax request and json as data type.

in my handler code i would like to return html table in string format. here is snap of my handler code

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";      
context.Response.Write(sResponse);
```

where sResponse contains `<table><tr><td>PropertyName</td><td>PropertyID</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td><td>1</td></tr></table>`

my jquery code (*check inline comment in error function*):

```
  id = { 'PropertyID': id };
    $.ajax("Handlers/GenericHandler.ashx?Type=getProperties",
    {
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);            
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            console.log(status); // Output as parseError
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // My sResponse string ! But Why Here ?
        }
    });
```

**My Question :**

1. Why i am not getting response in success function
2. Is it right way to do ? or should i convert html table to json object and then return it. And again display it in tabular format ?

Comment: The response isn't JSON, so why did you set `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: request data is in `JSON` thats why !

Comment: Change `dataType: 'json',` to `dataType: 'text/plain',`

Comment: @Satpal m getting same error if i change dataType to text/plain

Comment: Guys, I've a question regarding this topic. Isn't `$.ajax("Handlers/GenericHandler.ashx?Type=getProperties",` invalid? Can we use the `url` attribute like that?

Comment: Its not invalid as m not getting any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response isn't valid JSON sine it's returning plain text. jQuery is expecting the response to be JSON because you've set `contentType: "application/json"`

If the rest of your site uses JSON as a transmission format, then wrap your HTML as a JSON object and return it.

In your back end code, return something that looks like this

```
{response_html : "<table><tr><td>PropertyName</td><td>PropertyID</td></tr><tr><td>abc</td><td>1</td></tr></table>"}
```

And in your jQUery code, you can access it in the success callback.

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.response_html);            
},
```

NOTE - You'll need to remove the plain text content type from your backend code and make that JSON.

Answer (score 10):

From jQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you can see that the `dataType` parameter is what AJAX  is expecting back as a response from the server. The `contentType` parameter is what is put in the header in your request to the server so that the server knows how to read the request.

Therefore, you should change your `dataType` to "text" like:

```
$.ajax("Handlers/GenericHandler.ashx?Type=getProperties",
{
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(id),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);            
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText); 
    }
});
```

I find this useful when alerting of a successful INSERT or UPDATE call on a database. It would be extraneous to create and return a JSON object for such a task.

Answer (score 2):

If you tell `$.ajax` that you expect a JSON, then a `text/plain` response from the server is not a valid response.

Regarding your second question: The good way to do it would be to return the data you want to work with, in JSON format, for example:

```
[
  { "label" : "PropertyName", "value" : "abc" },
  { "label" : "PropertyId", "value" : "1" }
]
```

And then in the success callback of your Ajax request, work with that data to build your HTML structure with jQuery.